# Fragment Layout is blank

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I am passing an object (Contact) of type contacts, onclick in RecyclerView and displaying it in a Fragment in another activity using intents and Serialize. But the content is blank no fields displayed or titles.. blank layout not sure what the issue is here...

**Calling the activity with fragment**

```
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(context, ContactDetailsHome::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("contact", contact as Serializable)
        intent.putExtra("Edit", true)
        context.startActivity(intent)
    }
```

**Fragment Contact Details where the layout is generated**

class ContactDetails : Fragment() {

```
companion object {
    @JvmStatic
    fun start(context: Context, contact: Contact?, isEdit: Boolean) {
        val starter = Intent(context, ContactDetails::class.java)
            .putExtra("contact", contact as Serializable)
            .putExtra("Edit", isEdit)
        context.startActivity(starter)
    }
}

private lateinit var contact: Contact
private lateinit var numEditList: ArrayList<EditText>
private lateinit var emailEditList: ArrayList<EditText>


override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_contact_details, container, false)

    numEditList = ArrayList()
    emailEditList = ArrayList()

    return view
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    if (activity?.intent?.getBooleanExtra("Edit", false) == true){
        initEdit()
    }else{
        initAdd()
    }

    delete_contact!!.setOnClickListener {
        deleteContact()
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Contact Deleted Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        activity?.finish()
    }

}

private fun initEdit() {
    //getting the value from the object
    contact = (activity?.intent?.getSerializableExtra("contact") as Contact)
    //assigning it to fields to be displayed
    contDetails_name.setText(contact.name)

    if (contact.numbers.isEmpty()) {
        phoneTitle!!.visibility = View.GONE
    }

    if (contact.emails.isEmpty()) {
        title_emails!!.visibility = View.GONE
    }

    for (number in contact.numbers) {
        val editText = EditText(activity)
        editText.setText(number)
        editText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0D0D0D"))
        editText.typeface = Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD
        editText.textSize = 20f
        editText.isEnabled = false
        numEditList.add(editText)
        contact_numbers_layout!!.addView(editText)
    }

    for (email in contact.emails) {
        val editText = EditText(activity)
        editText.setText(email)
        editText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0D0D0D"))
        editText.typeface = Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD
        editText.textSize = 20f
        editText.isEnabled = false
        emailEditList.add(editText)
        contact_emails_layout!!.addView(editText)
    }

    edit_contact!!.setOnClickListener {
        if (contDetails_name.isEnabled) {
            if (contDetails_name.text.toString().isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Contact name can't be empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show()
            }
            contDetails_name.isEnabled = false
            for (editText in numEditList) {
                editText.isEnabled = false
            }

            for (editText in emailEditList) {
                editText.isEnabled = false
            }

            deleteContact()
            addContact()
            edit_contact.text = "Edit"
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Contact updated successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } else {
            contDetails_name.isEnabled = true
            for (editText in numEditList) {
                editText.isEnabled = true
            }

            for (editText in emailEditList) {
                editText.isEnabled = true
            }

            edit_contact.text = "Save"
        }
    }

}
```

**layout file**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Contacts.ui.ContactDetails">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/contDetails_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:hint="Contact Name"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:textColor="@color/txtcolor"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/phoneTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="Phone/Mobile No:"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/contact_numbers_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_emails"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="Email"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/contact_emails_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/edit_contact"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="Edit"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/delete_contact"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="Delete"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

discovered that I didn't declare view  during creation in oncreateView before returning it. resulting in no view being generated hence blank fragment.

Val view:View = ....
return view